# What are the differences between the usage of words that end with "ing" and those which do not?

Tags: word-usage

To my knowledge, when native speakers are using gerunds as a noun, they would prefer words that end with "-ment" rather than those that end with "ing." Is it just a personal preference, or a grammatical phenomenon?

Specifically, can the suffix "-ing" add some subtle meanings to a word in English?

There are two different ways to change a verb into a noun. The first way is to suffix "-ment", while the second way is to suffix "-ing" and make it a gerund. As those two ways are both grammatically correct, what are the differences between the meanings of the words yielded by these two approaches?

Comment: Compare "bling" and "blment". I've never heard anyone use the word "blment". Or strment. Or the famous US Sment Sment prison.

Comment: Maybe, as you mentioned, it's improper to say native speakers prefer words in -ing form. But, to clarify, I meant I don't understand what are the differences between words that in -ing form and in -ment form. According to my experience, it's correct to use words in ing form in some cases but is wrong in others.

Comment: I meant your question covers too many English words. You need to narrow down the words to a few specific nouns with examples/references.

Comment: @gnasher729 Say you got some words derived from the same word root like "enjoying" and "enjoyment". According to my dictionary, both of them have the same meaning, which makes me confused...

Comment: @Rathony I'm asking for a rule of thumb, if any.

Comment: Well, let me change into another way. As we all know, suffix "-ing" to a verb can change its part of speech from verb to noun. However, "-ment" serves the same function. So my question is, what are the differences between those words?

Comment: It is heavily context-dependent and usage-dependent. You can never say either of the two forms is preferred or more broadly used, i.e. contrast "My goal is ***improving*** English" with "My goal is ***improvement*** of English".

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as opinion-based.  I think we could say something about the difference between the gerund and nouns ending in -ment, even if the answer is "it's a matter of personal preference."

Comment: @ColleenV I don't think the answer would be "it's a matter of personal preference." It depends on the verb. The OP should edit the question to ask about a few specific verbs. Otherwise, it would be too broad for any answer.

Comment: @Rathony I'm not implying an answer,  I'm saying there is an answer to the question about whether there is a rule of thumb for choosing between them . The answer might be there's no general rule.  Specific examples would just confuse the question in my opinion.

Comment: @yummysushi Please post a couple examples you would like the willing and eager answerers to comment on. I can not think of any examples which fit your description of "-ing" or "-ment" being interchangeable. For example: "It is exciting", not "it is excitement", and usage between "-ing" and "-ment" tends to be mutually exclusive depending on context (a la @Ranthony)...

Answer (score 1):

This may just be my brain having a short holiday, but having come up short on gerunds that end in "-ment" (see what I did there?) I suspect that it is a grammatical phenomewnon.

The Cambridge English dictionary has gerund as

> "a word ​ending in "-ing" that is made from a ​verb and used like a ​noun."

So it seems they agree with me.

Reading the comments, I think I see the issue.  Improvement is a noun with the same etymological root as "to improve".  But crucially, it is a noun.  It is *not* a gerund.

A gerund is a verb participle *acting as* a noun. It is not, however, actually a noun.